# EME Key ID different in session request vs. message (ClearKey)

Tags: html, encryption, browser, drm

1. What is the relationship between the kid supplied to MediaKeySession.generateRequest() and the one provided via MediaKeyMessageEvent?
2. If they are supposed to be the same - why are they different in the code below? *note, this won't run here due to security restrictions*

```js
navigator.requestMediaKeySystemAccess("org.w3.clearkey", [{
    initDataTypes: ['webm'],
    audioCapabilities: [{
        contentType: 'audio/webm; codecs="opus"'
    }],
    videoCapabilities: [{
        contentType: 'video/webm; codecs="vp8"'
    },
    {
        contentType: 'video/webm; codecs="vp9"'
    }
    ],
}]).then((keySystemAccess) => {
    return keySystemAccess.createMediaKeys();
}).then((mediaKeys) => {
    var session = mediaKeys.createSession("temporary");
    var keyId = "VHM2iIMGiSg";
    var initData = '{"kids":["' + keyId + '"]}';
    console.log(keyId);

    session.addEventListener('message', (evt) => {
        var requestJson = new TextDecoder().decode(evt.message);
        var request = JSON.parse(requestJson);
        console.log(request.kids[0]);
    });

    this.session.generateRequest("webm", new TextEncoder().encode(initData));
});
```

output:

> VHM2iIMGiSg
>
> eyJraWRzIjpbIlZITTJpSU1HaVNnIl19

expected output is for second line to also be `VHM2iIMGiSg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`eyJraWRzIjpbIlZITTJpSU1HaVNnIl19` is the base64url encoded value of `initData` that was passed to `generateRequest`.

The reason that `request.kids[0]` is the full value of `initData` and not the value of `keyId` is because `generateRequest` was invoked with the `initDataType` parameter set to `webm`. Had the `initDataType` parameter been set to `keyids` then `request.kids[0]` would be the value of `keyId`.

When the `initDataType` parameter is set to `webm` the `initData` parameter is expected to be a [single key ID of one or more bytes](https://w3c.github.io/encrypted-media/format-registry/initdata/webm.html#h-format). Whereas when the `initDataType` parameter is set to `keyids` the `initData` parameter is expected to be a [JSON object encoded as UTF-8, containing a single member `kids` which is an array of base64url encoded Key ID(s)](https://w3c.github.io/encrypted-media/format-registry/initdata/keyids.html#h-format).